# Mathematica 11.3 not responding (OS X El Capitan)

Tags: kernel, crash

I first updated Mathematica from a previous version (11.0.1) to the newest (11.3) and any computation requiring the kernel would make the software freeze.
To solve the problem I tried completely uninstalling all the versions, and reinstalling from a freshly re-downloaded archive: no change, impossible to use Mathematica.

Is there any know issue/fix about some incompatibilities with this version?

Comment: I suggest you contact Wolfram Support...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some investigation, it appears that Avira's "Real-time protection" is somehow interfering with the execution of the kernel; the process `savapi` was using all the resources.
By disabling it or uninstalling Avira, the execution works fine.

(Note that Avira also slows down the startup of Matlab)